# How to push streamed music from iPad to TV

Tags: ipad, music, streaming

I have a Samsung UA46D8000, which is a really cool TV. It is plugged into my router and understands DNLA protocols.

The TV is great, however the remote is unsuitable for selecting music.

Here's what I'd like to do, however I don't know if it's possible.

I'd like to be able to select music on my iPad (which has a fantastic user interface), and then that music is pushed to the TV (either from a separate server or directly from the iPad over wifi)

Does anyone know how this can be done?

Cheers
Rich

p.s. I have tried AirMusic, but that creates a pull DNLA server, which is not what I want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way imho would be to buy an AppleTV2. It's cheap, and "it just works".

Edit: For completeness sake, I'll just clarify what you can expect from the AppleTV2. Since it is an AirPlay compatible reciever for both audio and video, you can stream music or videos being played on your iPad (or iPhone/iTunes for that matter) directly to your TV. On your computer, you can even stream any audio source through software like [Airfoil](http://www.rogueamoeba.com/airfoil/). Starting with iOS5, AirPlay even allows you to mirror your iPad on the television set.

Additionally, if you enable Home Sharing in iTunes on a connected computer, your iPad can serve as a remote to play content (audio/video) in your iTunes library directly on the TV. For this usecase the content doesn't even need to be on the iPad. You'll just need the [Remote app](http://www.apple.com/itunes/remote/) by Apple, available for free in the App Store. The only downside here is that your computer (and iTunes) need to be powered up to access the media.

Comment: I second the recommendation. Spend $99 and your remote is any iPad, iPod Touch, or iPhone.

Comment: Thanks for the extra info. If I enable home share will that act as a DNLA server? So my TV will recognize it?

Comment: No, Home Sharing is a proprietary Apple implementation.

Comment: Ah, so is there anything that will reflect a DLNA service that can be controlled via my iPad? I am reluctant to buy an AppleTV as I already have a media solution in place. All I want is the iPad controller.

Comment: There are several DLNA remote apps available in the App Store. Have a look if that suits you better.

Comment: I toyed with DLNA in my home theater/network as well, and when I got my AppleTV, I quit messing with such things. ATV is by far the easiest, cleanest, most "just works"-y media networking tool I've ever used. It's also the best Netflix terminal on the market, IMO.